# Generating a count of shared IDs between a tuple of item numbers

Tags: python

I have a group by object converted in to dataframe as :

```
Item       ID's

1           100,101,102
2           101,103,104
3           100,201,202
```

Now I want to generate 2-tuples/ordered pairs, that gives me count of the IDs shared in each pair of items.  The desired output is:

```
Item  Item  Id's
 1    2      5
 1    3      5
 2    3      6
```

The columns correspond to every ordered pair of items such as (1,2),(1,3),(2,3) and so on and then the third column tells me how many ids both items have in the original table.

Comment: Your explanation is a bit confusing, are you looking for a script to count what ids occur in both pairs of items? ie There are 5 in both item 1 and 2, then 6 in item 2 and 3?

Comment: Can you give an example of the required output in terms of python data structures e.g. `[(1,2), (3,4)]` and how these relate to your input data. As it stands I don't understand what it is you want.

Comment: Yes right...basically I want the unique ids occurring in every pair of items. If you see I have given the sample output as explained by you. Hope now it clears your doubt!!

Comment: @Rooney I have edited the question to make you understand understand the desired output. Basically I want to scan through every ordered pair and count the number of unique id's.

Answer (score 3):

If for structure you have something like:

```
data = {
    1: [100, 101, 102],
    2: [101, 103, 104],
    3: [100, 201, 202],
}
```

then this will help:

```
res = {}
items = data.keys()
for n, i in enumerate(items, start=1):
    for j in items[n:]:
        res[(i, j)] = len(
            set(data[i]).union(set(data[j]))
        )
```

Output:

```
res
{(1, 2): 5, (1, 3): 5, (2, 3): 6}
```

Comment: Thanks @pavel.....appreciate your help...only difference is I want the final output in columns as shown in the desired output...anyway I would figure out that...thanks again!!